# Calculate minutes between two datetime fields in pandas dataframe excluding weekends and holidays

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with two datetime fields (date_started and date_completed). I would like to calculate the number of minutes between these two datetimes for each row in the dataframe, EXCLUDING weekends and US holidays. My feeble attempt at this was as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import holidays as pyholidays

weekmask = 'Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu'
holidays = pyholidays.US
df['bus_days'] = df.apply(lambda x : len(pd.bdate_range(start=x.date_started, end=x.date_completed, freq='min', weekmask=weekmask, holidays=holidays)))
```

I'm getting AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'date_started'. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: missing `axis=1`, try `df['bus_days'] = df.apply(lambda x : len(pd.bdate_range(start=x.date_started, end=x.date_completed, freq='min', weekmask=weekmask, holidays=holidays)), axis=1)`

Comment: Ah, thank you. That does resolve the initial issue, but then results in an error stating that custom frequency must be used if weekmask or holiday schedule is used. Problem is, the only custom frequencies available are day or hour. Trying to figure out how to calculate at the minute frequency while still taking into account weekmask and holidays.

Answer (score -1):

```
from datetime import datetime

total = date_completed - date_started
seconds = total.total_seconds()
minutes = seconds/60
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this takes into account weekends or holidays?